# pandas: compare sum over two time periods?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
         prod_code      month  items      cost
0  040201060AAAIAI 2016-05-01      5    572.20   
1  040201060AAAKAK 2016-05-01    164  14805.19    
2  040201060AAALAL 2016-05-01  13465  14486.07
```

I would like to first group by the first four characters of `prod_code`, then sum the total cost of each group from Jan-Feb 2016, then compare this with the total cost from Mar-Apr 2016, then find the groups with the biggest percentage increase over the two time periods.

What's the best way to go about this?

Here is my code so far:

```
d = { 'prod_code': ['040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAJ', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040201060AAAIAI', '040301060AAAKAG', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAX', '040301060AAAKAK', '040301060AAAKAK'], 'month': ['2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01', '2016-01-01', '2016-02-01', '2016-03-01'], 'cost': [43, 45, 46, 41, 48, 59, 8, 9, 10, 12, 15, 13] }
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
df['para'] = df.prod_code.str[:4]
df_para = df.groupby(['para', 'month']).sum()
```

This gives me `df_para` which looks like this:

```
                 cost
para month
0402 2016-01-01    84
     2016-02-01    93
     2016-03-01   105
0403 2016-01-01    20
     2016-02-01    24
     2016-03-01    23
```

Now I need to calculate the sum for each group for Jan-Feb and for Apr-Mar, then the difference between those two groups, and finally sort by the difference between those two groups. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you please provide __reproducible__ input and desired data sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a month group variable based on whether the months are `Jan-Feb` or `Mar-Apr` and then group by the code and month group variable, summarize the cost and calculate the difference:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df['month_period'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime(df.month).dt.month.isin([1,2]), 1, 2)
# creation of the month group variable could be adjusted based on how you want to cut 
# your time, this is a simplified example which assumes you only have data from Jan-Apr

(df.groupby([df.prod_code.str[:4], df.month_period]).sum().groupby(level = 0).pct_change()
   .dropna().sort('cost', ascending=False))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this looks great! In reality I have five years of data and just want to compare Jan-Jun 2010 with Jan-Jun 2015 - what would be the best way to do this? I'd probably need three values for the dummy variable - say 1 for the first period, 2 for the second period, and null for everything else, but then how would I calculate `pct_change` between 1 and 2 only?

Comment: If you set 0 for everything else, then you could either filter out all 0 records before calculating the `pct_change` or it returns two pct_change for every group and the second one should be what you are looking for. I would probably just filter out records that don't fall within the date range that you are interested in.

Comment: Something like `cond1 = (df.month > '2010-01-01') & (df.month < '2010-06-30');cond2 = (df.month > '2015-01-01') & (df.month < '2015-06-30');df['month_period'] = np.where(cond1, 1, np.where(cond2, 2, 0)); df = df[df.month_period != 0];`